# HTML <dialog> close() does nothing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attaching confirmation `<dialog>`s to any forms that need them with

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form[data-confirm]");
forms.forEach((form) => {
  const confirm = document.createElement("dialog");
  const message = document.createElement("p");
  const cancel = document.createElement("button");
  const accept = document.createElement("button");
  message.innerText = form.dataset.confirm;
  cancel.innerText = form.dataset.cancel;
  accept.innerText = form.dataset.accept;
  confirm.appendChild(message);
  confirm.appendChild(cancel);
  confirm.appendChild(accept);
  form.appendChild(confirm);
  form.onsubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    confirm.showModal();
  }
  cancel.onclick = () => {
    console.log(confirm.close)
    confirm.close();
  }
  accept.onclick = () => {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

This seems to work well, apart from the `close()` method, which does *nothing* and throws *no error*. Logging the function to the console shows

```
function close()
length: 0
name: "close"
<prototype>: function ()
```

in Firefox, while Edge & Chrome show

> f close() { [native code] }

Changing the call to `hide()` as a test predictably results in

> Uncaught TypeError: confirm.hide is not a function

Logging the dialog itself shows that we're dealing with the right DOM object:

```js
...

cancel.onclick = () => {
    console.log(confirm)
    confirm.close();
}
```

```
> <dialog open="">
...

​<prototype>: HTMLDialogElementPrototype { show: show(), showModal: showModal(), close: close(), … }
```

There are no other dialogs on the page. I seem to be *the only one* who's run into this problem, which makes me think a facepalm moment is not far off. Can you deliver it?

Comment: You probably shouldn't put the `<dialog>` element *inside* the `<form>`

Comment: @Bergi why on earth not? Semantically it is part of the form.

Comment: @OlaTuvesson because then the buttons inside the dialog would interact with the form, as shown in Pete's answer, and you don't want that. You may in fact want to put a `<form method="dialog">` around the buttons inside the `<dialog>`.

Comment: @Bergi There can be lots of reasons why you would want to put `<button>`s inside a form that do not submit it.

Comment: @OlaTuvesson sure, but then better use `<input type="button">` or `<button type="button">`. However I was talking specifically about the cancel and accept buttons of your dialog.

Comment: @Bergi Will you let me off the hook if I change the button type on the cancel button to `type="button"`?

Comment: Sure, that's better :-) I probably would still recommend to make a separate `<form>` for the dialog and its buttons, and put that *next to* the original `<form>`, since - while they are clearly related - forms shouldn't be nested. But I don't think your approach is wrong either, especially if you want to consider the accept button as a `<button type="submit">` for the form in which the dialog resides. Not sure which is semantically cleaner.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you - that was my thinking, that the buttons in the dialog are for interacting with the form, and the "Ok" is basically another submit. There are different ways of looking at it though! Where I went wrong, fundamentally, was forgetting that the default behaviour of a plain `<button>` inside a `<form>` is to submit the form - which is somewhat unintuitive IMO. And `<button type="button">` feels clumsier than `<button type="submit">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to prevent the default action of the cancel button - as it's in the form it's probably closing the modal but submitting the form again and showing a new modal (if you change the cancel to a span instead of a button, you will see it works without the prevent default):

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form[data-confirm]");

forms.forEach(form => {
  const confirm = document.createElement("dialog");
  const message = document.createElement("p");
  const cancel = document.createElement("button");
  const accept = document.createElement("button");
  message.innerText = form.dataset.confirm;
  cancel.innerText = form.dataset.cancel;
  accept.innerText = form.dataset.accept;
  confirm.appendChild(message);
  confirm.appendChild(cancel);
  confirm.appendChild(accept);
  form.appendChild(confirm);
  
  form.onsubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    confirm.showModal();
  }
  
  cancel.onclick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    confirm.close();
  }
  
  accept.onclick = () => {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="get" data-confirm="confirm" data-cancel="cancel" data-accept="accept">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The form wasn't submitted since I `preventDefault` `onsubmit`, which made it appear as though the cancel button only triggered its own `onclick` and nothing else. I would have noticed the form submitting as there would have been a corresponding `POST` entry in the console - and the dialog would have disappeared. And to be perfectly honest I had forgotten that a `<button>` by default acts as `type="submit"` when placed inside a form... Cue lots of confusion!

Comment: By submitting the form, I meant it would re-trigger the `onsubmit` which then shows the modal (but not actually submit the form as you had the prevent default in the `onsubmit`)

Comment: Thank you. In the end I went with setting `cancel.type = "button"` instead, and dropping `event.preventDefault()` from the `onclick` event handler for it. A case of "six of one, half a dozen of the other" I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Every button inside the form will trigger submit when clicked so you are in a submit loop that technically close and reopen your dialog.

To fix this add `event.preventDefault();` inside every button of your dialog:

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form[data-confirm]");

forms.forEach((form) => {
  const confirm = document.createElement("dialog");
  const message = document.createElement("p");
  const cancel = document.createElement("button");
  const accept = document.createElement("button");
  message.innerText = form.dataset.confirm;
  cancel.innerText = form.dataset.cancel;
  accept.innerText = form.dataset.accept;
  confirm.appendChild(message);
  confirm.appendChild(cancel);
  confirm.appendChild(accept);
  form.appendChild(confirm);
  form.onsubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    confirm.showModal(); 
  }
  cancel.onclick = () => {
    //just add this for fix your problem
    //=================================
    event.preventDefault();
    //================================
    confirm.close();
  }
  accept.onclick = () => {
    //this is not mandatory but is usefull 
    //if you want add some logic inside accept
    //=================================
    event.preventDefault();
    //================================
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<form data-confirm="confirm" data-cancel="cancel"  data-accept="accept">
<h2>hero</h2>
<button>test</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's the same answer as that already given by @Pete. Correct but redundant.